# ClassCastException: io.realm.Realm cannot be cast to io.realm.Realm

Tags: kotlin, mockito, realm, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to mock a Realm instance. My implementation has been successful, but it fails when running multiple tests together.
Here is the implementation of a class to create the mocked Realm instance.

```
import android.os.Build
import io.realm.Realm
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

import io.realm.RealmConfiguration
import io.realm.RealmQuery
import io.realm.RealmResults
import io.realm.log.RealmLog
import io.realm.internal.RealmCore
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert
import org.junit.Rule
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.SuppressStaticInitializationFor
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic
import org.robolectric.RuntimeEnvironment
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config

@RunWith(value = RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(value = RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1])
@PowerMockIgnore(value = ["org.robolectric.*", "org.mockito.*", "android.*", "javax.net.ssl.*", "javax.security.*", "javax.crypto.*"])
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("io.realm.internal.Util")
@PrepareForTest(value = [Realm::class, RealmConfiguration::class, RealmQuery::class, RealmResults::class, RealmCore::class, RealmLog::class])
abstract class RealmPresenterTest { //Does not make difference as open class

  var mockRealm: Realm? = null

  @Rule @JvmField var rule = PowerMockRule()

  @Before open fun setUp() {
    mockStatic(RealmCore::class.java)
    mockStatic(RealmLog::class.java)
    mockStatic(Realm::class.java)
    mockStatic(RealmConfiguration::class.java)
    RealmCore.loadLibrary(RuntimeEnvironment.application)
    Realm.init(RuntimeEnvironment.application)

    val mockRealm = PowerMockito.mock(Realm::class.java)
    val mockRealmConfig = PowerMockito.mock(RealmConfiguration::class.java)

//    doNothing().`when`(RealmCore::class.java)
    PowerMockito.whenNew(RealmConfiguration::class.java).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockRealmConfig)
    PowerMockito.`when`(Realm.getInstance(ArgumentMatchers.any(RealmConfiguration::class.java))).thenReturn(mockRealm)
    PowerMockito.`when`(Realm.getDefaultInstance()).thenReturn(mockRealm)

    this.mockRealm = mockRealm

    MatcherAssert.assertThat(Realm.getDefaultInstance(), CoreMatchers.`is`(mockRealm))
  }

}
```

This class is extended in another class that uses this mocked Realm instance. The test **does** work normally if I run the class test itself.
But if I run multiple tests together (like running the folder with multiple classes inside), I get this error:

Where the exception happens:

```
val mockRealm = PowerMockito.mock(Realm::class.java)
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.realm.Realm cannot be cast to io.realm.Realm

    at com.app.RealmPresenterTest.setUp(RealmPresenterTest.kt:49)
    at com.app.SomePresenterTest.setUp(SomePresenterTest.kt:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1854)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:816)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:681)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.getResult(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:76)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.invokeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:64)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.executeWithClassLoader(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:56)
    at org.powermock.classloading.SingleClassloaderExecutor.execute(SingleClassloaderExecutor.java:33)
    at org.powermock.classloading.AbstractClassloaderExecutor.execute(AbstractClassloaderExecutor.java:40)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:75)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:305)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:546)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I'll remember seeing error message like that if there are multiple `class loaders` involved. Not sure so where they would come from in your case.

Comment: You mean multiple versions of `class loader`?

Comment: Not necessarily. The problem occurs when you have a `ClassLoader A` that loads some classes, and a `ClassLoader B` that loads the same classes. And somewhere in the code you now try to cast an object that was constructed with a class loaded from A to a class loaded by B.

Comment: Probably this is happening because I am configuring it using an abstract class?

Comment: I can not say. Those issues are hard to track down. It might also be an incompatibilty in the frameworks you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I will give a try.

Comment: @second Didn't help :(

Comment: @second I am trying to replicate this in a example app but had no success yet.

Comment: Keep trying. If I understand correctly you have multiple tests that when run in parralel cause this exception. Try to figure out which ones, isolate them from the rest and verify that its still happening. You might even track down the error that way ;)

Comment: @second is there any way to reset the classloader or Robolectric? Maybe this can help me.

Comment: You'll probaly need to go to their bugtracker and check whether there is already an open issue for your problem. Looks like they had similiar issues in the past (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2677). An update might help, otherwise its likely they still have some incompatibilities.

Comment: I have opened a new issue: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/996